# Meaning of the Accuracy value returned by Android GPS

Tags: android

I want to know that what is the meaning of the accuracy value returned by

```
location.getAccuracy()
```

**For example:** If it returns "1" , than what does it means?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The whole point of the accuracy level means that you're within X distance. Your returned location value was 20 meters from your actual position; the accuracy was 20 meters. That's the best you can do with that accuracy. You should get better accuracy than that if you're using GPS versus simple cell tower triangulation.

**The lower the number returned by `location.getAccuracy()` is, the more accurate it has.**

**`getAccuracy()` describes the deviation in meters. So, the smaller the number, the better the accuracy.**

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. I think the probability quoted by brianestey is an important point here. Moreover, saying *guaranteed [...] within X meters* is just wrong.

Comment: NOT guaranteed!!! The stated probability of being within the returned radius is 68% which means 32% of the time, the location given is outside the returned radius, perhaps by quite a distance although the probability of being further outside the radius is lower than being closer outside the radius.

Answer (score 73):

From the Android docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy())

> public float getAccuracy ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Get the estimated accuracy of this location, in
>   meters.
>
> We define accuracy as the radius of 68% confidence. In other words, if
>   you draw a circle centered at this location's latitude and longitude,
>   and with a radius equal to the accuracy, then there is a 68%
>   probability that the true location is inside the circle.
>
> In statistical terms, it is assumed that location errors are random
>   with a normal distribution, so the 68% confidence circle represents
>   one standard deviation. Note that in practice, location errors do not
>   always follow such a simple distribution.
>
> This accuracy estimation is only concerned with horizontal accuracy,
>   and does not indicate the accuracy of bearing, velocity or altitude if
>   those are included in this Location.
>
> If this location does not have an accuracy, then 0.0 is returned. All
>   locations generated by the LocationManager include an accuracy.

So basically, if it returns 1, that means there is a 68% probability that you are within 1 meter of the GPS location reported.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for it, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

location.getAccuracy() provides the float value representing accuracy in meters (radius). So if it returns 1 that means the object location is accurate to within 1 meter radius.

Lower the integer better the accuracy.